# Prove the inequality $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}<1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, trigonometry

Is there a good way to show that $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is bounded above by $1$?

We can see visually that $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is bounded above by $1$ because the tallest hump is at the origin and $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$. But is there a way to prove this rigorously? Preferably without expanding $\sin(x)$ into a Taylor series, unless Taylor series is the only way.

Comment: You just need for $x>0 \implies \sin x < x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly, $|\sin(x)|\leq |x|$ when $|x|>1$. For $|x|\leq 1$, you can use the mean value theorem to show that $x=0$ is the only solution to $\sin x=x$. Thus, $\sin x<x$ for $x>0$ and $\sin(x)>x $ for $x<0$. This implies that $$\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|\leq 1.$$

Comment: Like in the other deleted post, you just assumed what you are trying to prove, I think, by saying $|\sin(x)| \le |x|$ because that is synonymous to saying $|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}| \le 1$...

Comment: I perhaps. I did skip the detail that $|\sin (x)|\leq1$, but once this is known, it is obvious that the inequality holds for $|x|\geq 1$. Do you feel that $|\sin (x)|\leq 1$ needs to be proven?

Comment: Oh, I see, you wrote $|\sin(x)| \le 1 < |x|$ for $|x| > 1$, and the result follows for $|x| > 1$. Now I just have to address the $|x| \le 1$ case using the MVT.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this image of the unit circle where the area of the triangle is $\frac{1}{2}\sin(\theta)$ and the area of the circle sector is $\frac{1}{2}\theta$.

[image]

You can see that $\frac{1}{2}\sin(\theta) \le \frac{1}{2}\theta.$

Comment: +1 Absolutely brilliant! One of the best visual proofs I've ever seen! (Posted a whole 7 years later lol)

Answer (score 1):

Use
$\sin'(x)
=\cos(x)
$,
and
$\cos(x) \le 1$
to get,
for $x \ge 0$,
$\sin(x)
=\int_0^x \cos(t)dt
\le \int_0^x 1dt
=x
$.

Answer (score -2):

L'Hopital's rule works:
$$
    \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{\ x}
$$
Becomes
$$
    \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos(x)}{\ 1}
$$
Evaluating to
$$
    1
$$

It may not be as rigorous as you want though.

Comment: l'Hopital doesn't imply boundedness by $1$.